# How to import google form response into specific cells in an existing template

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

I am trying to create a user friendly way to fill out a questionnaire using google forms but import the responses into specific cells within an existing spreadsheet.

So, each child has their own spreadsheet that compiles their data. I have a template that lists each question and has a cell for a numeric response.

- Currently, I have the spreadsheet set up where the parents select their numeric response from a scale: 0, 1, 2, 3, 4 using a dropdown per question. But there are over 240 questions, which is both time consuming on their end and would also give them access to additional data in "hidden sheets" from the clinicians, even if the sheets are protected from editing.

So, I am wanting to create a form that is connected to the child's spreadsheet that the parents can fill out and their responses will be imported into the respective cells that match up with each question on the data sheet.

- For example, if a parent selects a rating of “4” on the google form in response to a question of the level of independence of their child for question 1 (or in my example it asks how much you like pizza), I’d want their response of “4” to be reflected in the child’s respective data sheet in cell T16 within the template I have created in the screenshot below, (which will be attached once my account allows it).
- Then the numeric response to question 2 "how many toppings do you like on your pizza?" would be reflected in cell T17, which in my example is "1".

The responses would need to be in cells T16:T31, T38:T64, T71:T97, and onward in sections.

It would also need to import the child's name and the submission date in respective cells as well, as highlighted in yellow in the screenshot.

An additional parameter: Each child has their own spreadsheet, so the link to the parent form would somehow need to be automatically connected to each child separately whenever a new copy of the data sheet was created. So that way an infinite number of children have their own dataset.

I hope this makes sense! Any help would be much appreciated! Please let me know if additional clarification is needed!

I have attached a sample that follows a similar concept in terms of where data needs to be recorded.

Comment: Please attach (a copy of) the Google Sheet.

Comment: If you wish more help please attach images or tables because some of us will not following links to your account because it exposes both of our emails and also sometimes shared links are hard to remove.

Comment: It does make some sense.  I think we get the basic idea.  The problem is that we need to be able to have a table of data that connects the question and answer to the exact page and exact range on each page where the information is to be stored.  Unfortunately, that appears to be in your head and not in your questioin.  It sounds like something that can easily be done with onFormSubmit trigger and some additional detail information.  Please note I will not follow links to documents on your google account.

Comment: I don't currently have enough reputation points to post images. But I have added further details that will hopefully help! I will add an image once my account allows it!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.